# matTooltip is not working consistently when used with mat-icon-button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two `mat-icon-button` buttons and for `clear` button `matToopTip` is working but not for the `done` button. What could be a possible reason for this?

```
<button *ngIf="field.isEditMode"
    type="button"
    mat-icon-button
    color="primary"
    (click)="saveField(field)"
    matToolTip="Save changes">
    <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
</button>
&nbsp;
<button *ngIf="field.isEditMode"
    type="button"
    mat-icon-button
    color="warn"
    (click)="cancelEditMode(field)"
    matTooltip="Cancel changes">
    <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: You have a typo in the tooltip for the first button, it should be matTooltip instead of matToolTip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spelled it `matToolTip` in the case where it's not working. Change the second T to lower case; `matTooltip` :)